# Read CMD console output for keyword

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a simple `.bat` script that runs an external console program and when it completes it outputs a couple lines of data.

**Is there a way to look for a keyword in the console output after external program has completed.**

For instance:
The external program completes, the `.bat` file looks for the keyword: success, and if it's found it saves the console output conversely if the keyword is: failed then the `.bat` program exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually checks for success are done by directly checking the external process's [return code](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php) with the [`IF ERRORLEVEL`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69576) construct:

```
external.exe
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 GOTO error1
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO error2
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO error3
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error4
REM if you reached this point, external.exe reported success
```

Of course this is dependent on the external program, so you might simply not be able to use it. In that case you can redirecting the output of the external program and using `find` to look for it; `find` uses a nonzero (don't remember exactly) return code to signify that the target string was not found. So you can write:

```
external.exe | find >nul "success"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO notfound
REM if you reached this point, "success" was present in the output
```

The `>nul` redirection makes sure that `find` will not actually output any matching text, since that's not what you want to do.

Comment: I was able to save the output of the exteneral program with `external.exe > output.txt` and was able to search the text file to find the keyword. However I can't interact with the program if I save it to file. Just running the exe (without saving to file) allows me to press 3 keys to quit show the status or pause. With my method of saving to a text file the console is blank until the program finishes and have to use `type>output.txt` to see what happened. Anyway around that?

Comment: @Nick: You want the equivalent of the unix [`tee`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) command, which "forks" its input to two or more outputs (redirect `external` output to `tee`, then `tee` redirects both to a file and back to the console). Googling should find Windows ports of it.